# Symbolic manipulation of expression with undefined function

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation

I have an expression which is a sum of undefined function `v[n1,n2,n3,n4]` with 4 arguments (`n_i` are integers):

```
expr=a*v[n1, n2, n3, n4] + b*v[n5, n6, n7, n8] + c*v[n9, n10, n11, n12] + ....
```

Now I increase or decrease the `i`-th argument of `v` in `expr`, and also multiply each term with the value of `v[[i]]`.

For example:

```
example=v[1,1,1,1]+10*v[0,0,2,0]
inc[example,3] (* first argument is the expression, second argument is the index of v that should be increased *)
(*
   example -> example=v[[3]]*v[1,1,1+1,1]+10*v[[3]]*v[0,0,2+1,0]
           -> example=1*v[1,1,2,1]+10*2*v[0,0,3,0]
*)
```

In reality, my `v` has much more terms, therefore hardcoding `inc` for each index is not feasible. I think I know how to do it with an ugly `For` loop, but I hope that there is some clever *Mathematica*-style way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
example = v[1, 1, 1, 1] + 10*v[0, 0, 2, 0];
```

Using a replacement rule:

```
inc[ex_, p_] := 
  ex /. v[a_, b_, c_, d_] -> 
     {a, b, c, d}[[p]] (v @@ ({a, b, c, d} +  UnitVector[4, p]))
```

and for a more general case - i.e., for an arbitrary number of arguments of `v` ([thanks: kgrl](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134394/symbolic-manipulation-of-expression-with-undefined-function/134395#comment362630_134395)):

```
inc[ex_, p_] := ex /. v[a__] :> {a}[[p]] (v @@ ( {a} + UnitVector[Length@{a}, p] ))
```

Then

```
inc[example, 3]
```

> 20 v[0, 0, 3, 0] + v[1, 1, 2, 1]

and

```
inc[example, 2]
```

> v[1, 2, 1, 1]

Comment: wow that is very beautiful. i was trying replacement rules for some time, but didnt know how to access one particular element of v[..]. It is very clever how you get a specific argument by producing a list and selecting it via [[p]] - Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you like it!

Comment: `Array[KroneckerDelta, {4, 4}]` is just `IdentityMatrix[4]`, no? And, since you're just extracting the `p`-th row, then what you actually want is `UnitVector[4, p]`...

Comment: @J.M. Ha! I had a feeling something is way too complicated here. Thanks.

Comment: (+1) perhaps slightly simpler and more general: `ex /. v[a__] :> {a}[[p]] (v @@ ({a} + UnitVector[Length[{a}], p]))`

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** a simpler version for OP's specific case:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[exp_, p_] := exp /. v[x__] :> v[x][[p]] MapAt[1 + # &, v[x], {p}]

exp = 10 v[0, 0, 2, 0] + v[1, 1, 1, 1] + k v[1, 2, 3, 4];
f2[exp , 2]
```

> `v[1, 2, 1, 1] + 2 k v[1, 3, 3, 4]`

```
f2[exp, 3]
```

> `20 v[0, 0, 3, 0] + v[1, 1, 2, 1] + 3 k v[1, 2, 4, 4]`

**Original post:**

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo = # /. a : #2[__] :> a[[#4]] MapAt[#3, a, {#4}] &;
(* or foo[exp_, func_, tr_, p_]:= exp/. a: func[__] :> a[[p]] MapAt[tr, a, {p}] *)
```

Examples:

```
example = v[1, 1, 1, 1] + 10*v[0, 0, 2, 0] + 5 w[1, 2, 3];

foo[example, v, 1 + # &, 2]
```

> `v[1, 2, 1, 1] + 5 w[1, 2, 3]`

```
foo[example, v, 1 + # &, 3]
```

> `20 v[0, 0, 3, 0] + v[1, 1, 2, 1] + 5 w[1, 2, 3]`

```
foo[example, v, h, 3]
```

> `20 v[0, 0, h[2], 0] + v[1, 1, h[1], 1] + 5 w[1, 2, 3]`

```
foo[example, w, h, 3]
```

> `10 v[0, 0, 2, 0] + v[1, 1, 1, 1] + 15 w[1, 2, h[3]]`

```
foo[example, w | v, h, 3]
```

> `20 v[0, 0, h[2], 0] + v[1, 1, h[1], 1] + 15 w[1, 2, h[3]]`

Comment: Thanks for this solution. For my problem it is overkill, but it uses some really fancy tricks which i would like to understand and which might be useful in near future. I have a problem understanding how you get the parameter from the function all with your ``a`` and ``Pattern``, could you maybe explain that idea a bit please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NicoDean, `a: v[___]` is the pattern `v[___]` with the assigned name `a`; so `a[[p]]`  gives Part `p` of it. In the simpler version in the update the part `p` of the pattern `v[x__]` is obtained using `v[x][[p]]`. Although it is not explicitly stated in the documentation, but `Part` is not restricted to `List` objects only; it  can be also used for expressions other than lists. Try, for example, `g[x,y,z,w][[2]]` and  `g[x,y,z,w][[{2}]]` Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = Module[{data},
  data = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 5}];
  Total[First[#] v[Sequence @@ Rest@#] & /@ data]]
```

> `9 v[5, 3, 3, 3] + v[8, 2, 9, 1] + 2 v[8, 5, 3, 1]`

Capturing argument `i` with the help of `Repeated` pattern object.

```
inc[i_ /; 1 <= i <= 4] :=
 a_. v[x : Repeated[_, {i - 1}], y_, z___] :> a y v[x, y + 1, z]

expr /. inc[3]
```

> `27 v[5, 3, 4, 3] + 9 v[8, 2, 10, 1] + 6 v[8, 5, 4, 1]`